# Is using "try" to see if a variable is defined considered bad practice in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I have the following piece of code inside a function:

```
try:
    PLACES.append(self.name)
except NameError:
    global PLACES
    PLACES = [self.name]
```

Which causes `from <file containing that code> import *` to return

```
SyntaxWarning: name 'PLACES' is used prior to global declaration
  global PLACES
```

So I was wondering if it is considered bad practice to do such a thing, and if so, what is the correct way of doing it? I'm a noob btw.

Comment: Imo you should write your code to ensure that PLACES will always be initialized ahead of time, no matter how it is used. Otherwise it looks ugly if you have to write it like that. (And you definitely should try to wean off using globals, as if two pieces of code use the same global but want to use it differently, there will be catastrophe!)

Comment: Take a step back, and ask yourself how it could be that `PLACES` isn't defined at this point in your code. I suspect you'll find a design error to fix, without needing a run-time check for the name.

Comment: Yes, this is a 'code smell'. @user2436558 we'd need to see the rest of your code to suggest how to improve it.

Comment: If `PLACES` is global, just declare it at the beginning of the function. Note it's a common coding convention to use all uppercase variable names to indicate that they is should be treated as a constants and never be modified (or initialized).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is you shouldn't do `from foo import *`, this is just bad practice and will cause namespace collisions (without any warnings, by the way), and will cause you headaches later on.

If you need to share a global storage space between two modules; consider pickling the object and unpickling it where required; or a k/v store, cache or other external store.  If you need to store rich data, a database might be ideal.

Checking if a name points to a object is usually a sign of bad design somewhere.  You also shouldn't assume to pollute the global namespace if a name doesn't exist - how do you know `PLACES` wasn't deleted intentionally?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out other mistakes as well. I was just looking for a framework or something to work with MySQL and Python so I guess I'll just toss `places` to the db.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is considered a bad practice. Just make sure the variable is defined. Virtually always, this is as simple as as module-level assignment with a reasonable default value:

```
Places = []
```

When the default value should not be instantiated at import time (e.g. if it is very costy, or has some side effect), you can at least initialize `None` and check whether `the_thing is None` when it's needed, initializing it if it's still `None`.

Comment: What is the difference to my answer, since you commented about a redundant test?

Comment: @MikeMüller Regarding what to assign to `PLACES`, our answers are identical. My comment was about first version of your answer, which simply stated that `if PLACES` could be used to detect the empty list as if this made an impact on appending to the list. The direct equivalent to OP's logic, `if PLACES: places.append(self.name) else: PLACES = [self.name] ` would redundantly special-case the empty list.

Comment: Ok. I meant to check if the list is empty, which is likely something you are interested in at some point. I assumed the OP was using the existence of the object for this. My answer was not as complete as should have been for this type of question.

Comment: @MikeMüller No worries, editing and improving answers is okay (expected even, depending on who you ask).

Answer (score 1):

I only suggest you move global PLACES out of except block:

```
global PLACES
try:
    PLACES.append(self.name)
except NameError:
    PLACES = [self.name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define:

```
PLACES = []
```

before anything else.

Than later:

```
PLACE.append(self.name)
```

If checked with

```
if PLACES:
```

an empty list yields false. This way you can tell if there are any places there already. Of course, you don't need to check anymore before you append.

Comment: For OP's code, the test becomes redundant and one can just call `.append` unconditionally.

Comment: You would need an extra check for `is None` and than create a new list. What do gain from this vs. just append to an empty list?